# Cronjob: Execute n instances of the command at once

Tags: ubuntu, cron

Currently, to launch n instances of script, I duplicate the following line n times in crontab.

```
* * * * * php some-script
* * * * * php some-script
...
n times
```

Is there anyway to launch n instances at once in a one line?

Answer (score 0):

Write a script as below and save it as (eg: phpcron.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..50}
do
   php some_script
   # do something else (pauses, error handling etc if needed )
done
```

Add this script to cron

```
* * * * * sh /path/to/phpcron.sh
```